# Convet htaccess to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I have transferred my server apache to Nginx but I face problem on our .htaccess rewrite rule
I have this rule on .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dl/(\w+)/(\w+)/(.*)/?$ download.php?pt=$1&tk=$2&flen=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I try this code in Nginx but not working

```
http{

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  *.oursitename.com;
        location / {
            rewrite ^dl/(\w+)/(\w+)/(.*)/?$ download.php?pt=$1&tk=$2&flen=$3 last;
        }
    }
}
```

I put location like `location /` because our `download.php` file in public_html main area.
please tell me how to it is working fine help me thanks

Comment: All URIs in Nginx begin with a leading `/`. So your regular expression should begin with `^/dl/...` and the rewritten URI should be `/download.php` if it's in the document root. Obviously the `server` block in your question is heavily edited, because you have no way to process the request to `/download.php`.

Comment: i not understand you second answer . if file in root place then not need server {} mean i put like this only http{ location / {}}

Comment: and place / in start like you say but not working

Answer (score 0):

With the following [rewriter](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx):

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    rewrite ^/dl/(\w+)/(\w+)/(.*)/?$ /download.php?pt=$1&tk=$2&flen=$3 last;
}
```